# ASP.NET MVC, how to get field count based on specific searches?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have table named `StaffOffenses` with data provided as shown image below. How to display if the `OffenseTypeID` column has total of 3 of the same value?

As you can see in the screenshot below, for `OffenseTypeID = 1` has total of 3, `OffenseTypeID = 2` has total of 1, `OffenseTypeID = 3` has total of 1, `OffenseTypeID = 4` has total of 1, and `OffenseTypeID = 5` has total of 1.

**TABLE**

[image]

**Controller**

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var getStaffOffenseRow = db.StaffOffenses.Where(x => x.StaffID == 555).Tolist();

var ifValueIs3 = null;
foreach(var item in getStaffOffenseRow)
{
    //at this point I have no idea what to do
}

if(ifValueIs3 == 3)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Use a `.GroupBy()` where the `.Count()` is >= 3

Comment: Dont quite understand. Is it like this? `var getStaffOffenseRow = db.StaffOffenses.Where(x => x.StaffID == 555).GroupBy(x => x.OffenseTypeID).Count();`

Comment: Not sure what you want to display in the results, but something like `db.StaffOffenses.Where(x => x.StaffId == 555).GroupBy(x => x.OffenceTypeId).Where(x => x.Count() >= 3).Select(x => new { Offence = x.Key, Total = x.Count() });`

Comment: may i know why you put `Offense` and `Total` in `{ Offence = x.Key, Total = x.Count() });`? What does it do? What do I search in google to learn more about this?

Comment: As I noted, I have no idea what data you want to return - the code I gave you returns a collection of anonymous objects containing the value of `OffenceTypeId` (the `Offense` property) and the number of times it occurs (the `Total` property) - which in the case of the data above will contain one item with `{ Offence = 1, Total = 3 }`

Comment: I wanted to display the `StaffId`, `OffenceTypeId` and the total number...is it possile to put in ViewBag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166659/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-learnprogramming).